# React/Redux fails when a Select option is selected the first time but not the second

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux

I'm developing a [React/Redux CRUD form](https://github.com/aarkerio/vet4pet/blob/master/app/assets/frontend/javascripts/components/AppoModalNewComponent.js).

**SOLVED**: Since I'm using Redux, the state should be changed by Redux after the API has been called and not with *this.setState*.

The logic is very basic: user selects the owner in the OwnerList, and then a list of his/her pets appears in the second Select Form element.

This method is called when the user selects an owner from the Select element:

```
  changeOwner(value) {
    this.setState({owner_id: value['value']});    // set owner
    let action = ApposActionCreators.getPets(value['value'], true);
    this.props.dispatch(action); // API call
    this.setState({pets_options: this.props.pets_options}); // set pets
  }
```

This is the owner select element:

```
<Select name="owners" options={this.state.owners_options} value={this.state.owner_id} onChange={this.changeOwner.bind(this)} />
```

The pet element:

```
 <Select ref="petSelect" autofocus options={this.state.pets_options} name="selected-pet" value={this.state.pet_id} onChange={this.changePet.bind(this)} searchable={true} />
```

I can load the owner list successfully, but when the user selects an element from the owner list the first time, the pets element is **not** populated even when the action and the reducer worked fine. The **second and subsequent times** all works correctly, the problem is in the first time.

[image]

I tried several things like set a setTimeout but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that `setState` is *asynchronous*. This might be the source of your problem.

Comment: API Call? So how would this data be instantly available? It seems to me it could take up to several seconds (maybe upgrade your backend if that's the case). Also, just because you dispatched an action and the state is modified, doesn't mean your props are updated. `this.props.pets_options` can't be updated until after `componentWillReceiveProps` was called. API calls are not instant. You can only render with data you already have now. That's why we have spinners and such.

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.dispatch()` doesn't guarantee that you will have proper values in `this.props.pets_options` immediately after dispatch call. If you want to do something with new props values you have to use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({pets_options: nextProps.pets_options})
}
```